# Map/Swap Values in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

For every column, need to find its average and and replace the column values with 1 if the value is greater than the average and -1 if it is less than the average. Finally, return the transformed data frame with the same columns and index as for the original.

```
  Column 1   Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column6
1    2          0       0        0         0        0           
2    0          0       0        0         0        0
3    0          1       1        2         1        1


Expected output:

  Column 1   Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column6
1     1         -1       -1        -1      -1       -1           
2    -1         -1       -1        -1      -1       -1 
3    -1          1        1         1       1        1


code so far:
import pandas as pd
def mapvalues(filename):
    mylist=[]
    data=pd.read_csv(filename)
    length=data.shape[0]
    width=data.shape[1]
    for i in range(3):
        columns=data.iloc[:,i]
        average=columns.mean()
        for j in columns:
            if j > average:
                mylist.append(1)
                
            else:
                mylist.append(-1)
    return(ListOfLists)
        
 mapvalues(path)
```

I had thought of appending the values into a list of lists([[1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,1]]) and then converting it to a data frame but I am unable to make that list of lists.

Any insights will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.mean()` to get the mean, `gt` to compare, then some math:

```
out = 2 * df.gt(df.mean()) - 1

# also
# out = 2 * (df > df.mean()) - 1
```

Output:

```
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4  Column 5  Column6
1         1        -1        -1        -1        -1       -1
2        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1       -1
3        -1         1         1         1         1        1
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks man. Clearly I have a long way to go.